# Throw error if element passed to class isn't svg (typescript)

Tags: typescript, svg

I have a typescript class that takes an svg html element (`<svg></svg>`)as a parameter:

```
export class MyClass extends Base {
  private svg: SVGSVGElement;
  constructor(svg: SVGSVGElement) {
  }
}
```

You would call it in javascript like this:

```
new MyClass(document.getElementById("mySVGElement"));
```

The problem is, if I pass a different element than a svg, nothing happens. How can I throw an error if the html element passed isn't an svg? Like:

```
constructor(svg: SVGSVGElement) {
  if (svg not svg) {
    //throw error
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the element to the constructor. Please give some examples if you have more than one method.

Comment: Are you passing your SVG as a string to the constructor?

Comment: Updated post including passing the element.

Comment: Well, `document.getElementById("mySVGElement")` will give you a `HTMLElement` type not a `SVGSVGElement` so you have a problem there already...

Comment: Why don't you just check `instanceof`? Also how is TS not already complaining in the constructor call? `Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SVGSVGElement'.`? You should probably do the check when *calling* the contructor.

Comment: Is the problem based on typo? Maybe you want `SVGElement` instead of `SVGSVGElement`? You can use `if(svg instanceof SVGElement)` to check the instance of the html element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `SVGSVGElement` is a class right?
How about `if(svg instanceof SVGSVGElement){ stuff }`

Answer (score 2):

In typescript, `document.getElementById` returns `HTMLElement | null` (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/025d82633915b67003ea38ba40b9239a19721c13/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L4517)) and it is not possible to convert `HTMLElement` into `SVGSVGElement` (see [here](https://zhirzh.github.io/prototype-tree/build/index.html?data=browser)and search for "HTMLElement").

This means that you have to "assume" the correct type inside constructor parameters and "check" for correctness inside constructor body.

```js
export class MyClass extends Base {
  private svg: SVGSVGElement;

  constructor(svg: SVGSVGElement) {
    if (svg instanceof SVGSVGElement === false) {
      throw Error()
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

There is an active discussion about changing the behaviour of `document.getElementById` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4689).

Answer (score 0):

You could make the parameter type to be 'any' and check if it svgsvgelement then .

Probably not the best way though ..

Answer (score 0):

You can check the files MIME type with file.type

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type

you can simply preform a check like this

```
if (!file.type == "image/svg+xml"){
   throw new Error('FileType is invalid');
}
```

Comment: Would an `<svg></svg>` be considered a file? I think my question is more generally about html elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
new MyClass(document.getElementById("mySVGElement"));
```

should cause a compiler error because `Document.getElementById` returns an `HTMLElement`.  So you already have type-safety at compile time.  However, if you still need to enforce this at runtime, then [Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55357842/976126) should be the canonical way to check at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MyClass extends Base {
    constructor(svg: SVGSVGElement) {
        if (svg instanceof SVGElement !== true) {
            throw new Error('Invalid element passed to constructor!')
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the code stefan-wullems was talking about would look like.